# Ruby object cache

Tags: ruby, caching, dictionary

I have a number of Ruby objects with unique IDs that I am currently caching in a Hash. When an object is assigned an ID, it goes into the Hash. The cache is complete, i.e. every object with an ID that exists in the Ruby scope should also be in the cache.

However, I am having trouble finding a way to delete objects from the cache once they disappear from all other scopes. This is, of course, because objects contained in the cache will not be garbage collected.

Are there any approaches to this problem? The documentation for [`WeakRef`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0/libdoc/weakref/rdoc/WeakRef.html#label-Example) suggests a `WeakHash` class, but it does not seem acceptable for practical use, although it is very close to what I think I need for my project.

Comment: Why would it not be practical?

Comment: WeakRef is what you need.

Answer (score 3):

Something similar to WeakHash will do it. Here's a more complete implementation that can handle Fixnums, Symbols, and Floats (and other immutable types if you add them to the list):

```
class WeakHash < Hash
  def []=(k, v)
    if(![Fixnum, Symbol, Float].include? k.class)
      k = WeakRef.new(k)
    end
    if(![Fixnum, Symbol, Float].include? v.class)
      v = WeakRef.new(v)
    end
    super k,v
  end
end
```

Comment: This is very similar to the example given in the WeakRef documentation, but isn't there a memory leak here? The objects stored in this hash are in fact garbage collected, but `weakhash.count` never decreases. Is this a bad thing?

Comment: @Vortico: Not a memory leak. Just, well, a count leak. I'll edit and fix that.

Comment: you can use `unless` instead of `if !`

Comment: How do you lookup a value once it is in the cache? You cannot simply use [] as that tries to lookup the original rather than the WeakHash instance... ???

Comment: @HenrikLindberg: You're absolutely right, and I'm not quite sure how to fix this -- the WeakRef documentation says that they can be used exactly like the object they reference, but apparently this doesn't extend to hashcode. You probably have to subclass `WeakRef` with some new class like `WeakKey` that also overrides `eql?` or `equal?` or `hash` (it's been a long time since I've written Ruby) to use the referenced object's implementation